# Read numbers from sscanf are 0

Tags: c, file-io, zero

Good day to the community. The code I am trying to write must should read integers from a file while skipping lines that start with #. My problem is that no numbers are read and instead the it returns 0.
The file looks like this:

```
#hello
#myname
#is
#file
122 4838
112   393949
1239 233
29393 44949
3 2
445 566
```

The output is:

```
0       0
Read 0 numbers
0       0
Read 0 numbers
0       0
Read 0 numbers
0       0
Read 0 numbers
```

The code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct {
    int start;
    int end;
} path;
int main()
{
    int test; 
    path* array=malloc(sizeof(path));
    if(array==NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory\n");
        abort();
    }


    FILE* fd=fopen("Test.txt","r");
    if(fd==NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
        abort();
    }
    char buff[200];
    int counter=0;

    char c;
    while(fgets(buff,200,fd)&&counter<6) {
        c=buff[0];
        if(c=="#") {
            continue;
        }
        test=sscanf(&buff,"%d%d",array[counter].start,array[counter].end);
        printf("%d\t%d\n",array[counter].start,array[counter].end);
        printf("Read %d numbers\n", test);
        counter++;
    }

    fclose(fd);
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should not ask a new question by editing an already existing one, even if it seems similar to you. Any change which makes an existing answer look wrong should be avoidded. I am not sure whether I read your comments correctly. It seems that the two of you were lucky. In this special case you  can keep it as is, but for the future please understand that editing when an answer is present is considered "moving target questions" and not at all appreciated. Please offer to @AdrianMole to rollback your recent edits to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is in your arguments to the `sscanf` function. This requires the **addresses** of all variables that are the 'targets' for corresponding format fields (but reading in `char[]` strings is different, as the array name will [*decay* to a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/10871073) when used as a function argument).

So, in your case, to read in the two integer structure members, you should use this:

```c
test = sscanf(buff, "%d%d", &array[counter].start, &array[counter].end);
```

Note 1: Also, you don't need the `&` operator on the `buff` argument, as this will decay, as mentioned above!

Note 2: Because the `.` (structure-member access operator) has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the `&` (address-of operator), the expression `&array[counter].start` is the same as `&(array[counter].start)` - but you *may* prefer the latter, more explicit code, as this *can* make things clearer for others to read and understand.

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: :-) From the timing I guess you were already in the process of editing when I commented. Good work.

Comment: And that with a single typo. Impressive.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out. I would choose this answer but I stumbled into another problem. I would make another question but the problem is a bit similar so I decided to edit this one.

Comment: @Azzarian It's a simple typo: in `if(c=="#")...` you are comparing the single character, `c` to a string! Use this instead, and everything should be tickety-boo: `if(c=='#')…` (single quotes, not double). (Sorry that I missed it when posting my answer!)

Comment: @Adrian Mole you are a genious, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: As you can see, I explained to asker that "moving target questions" should be avoided. Consider letting them know that you are Ok with the question as is. (Assuming I got the situation right.) I see you as entitled to request rollback. In fact I normally rollback question edits like this, but I leave it up to you. You have my support either way.